# How to avoid printing \part pages in Legrand Orange Book?

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, legrandorangebook

I am trying to remove the \part pages from my output as it is a needless feature.
The class has a custom command producing and printing the graphics and pages, but if I comment out parts of it or the whole block, it breaks my document in other places.

```
%Command to create and output the parts pages
\newcommand{\outputpartpage}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=center, rectangle, fill=ocre!20, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth] at (current page.center) {}; % Background color
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, xshift=\Gm@lmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north west) {\fontsize{220pt}{220pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{ocre!40}{#1}}; % Part number
        \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\strut #2}}; % Part title
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=\Gm@bmargin] at (current page.south east) { % Mini table of contents
            \parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{ % Width of box holding the mini ToC
                \printcontents[part]{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} % Display the mini table of contents showing chapters and sections, change tocdepth to 2 to also show %subsections or 0 to only show chapters
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}

\titleformat
    {\part} % Section type being modified
    [block] % Shape type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
    {\startcontents[part]\outputpartpage{\thepart}{#1}} % Format of the whole section
    {} % Format of the section label
    {0em} % Space between the title and label
    {} % Code before the label
    [] % Code after the label
```

I have also tried to avoid using the \part command totally and use

```
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Guidance document}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}
```

But this breaks the display of part numbers in TOC as seen below:

Is there another way please?

[image: TOC for the part missing part number]

[image: \part separator page to be removed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** To suppress the part page, while keeping the ToC style, add before `\begin{document}`

```
\newcounter{partx}
\renewcommand{\thepartx}{\Roman{partx}}
\newcommand{\partx}[1]{%
\stepcounter{partx}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepartx}#1}
```

and use the command `\partx{<part title>}` instead of `\part` like

```
\partx{Guidance document}
```

[image: x]

Comment: Thank you Simon. I would like to suppress the whole Part page from being printed out. When I use the \addcontentsline instead of \part, the Part page is not printed anymore (great) but the box with Part number also disappears from the TOC entry as seen on my TOC screenshot.

Comment: @David Vrabec Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, it has worked.